# PLSQL loop through dates and use it as a parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, parameters

So I am trying to find a correct method to use each date from the query below to be used as a parameter for another query

```
SELECT to_char(dates,'yyyy-mm-dd') dates
FROM (
    SELECT TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019') + ROWNUM - 1 dates
        FROM (
          SELECT ROWNUM FROM (
            SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= sysdate - (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019') + 1 )
          )
    )
)
```

EX. select netcash from tb1 where tb1.cutoff_date = :dates (where the value for :dates is coming from the subquery)

Answer (score 0):

Use a common table expression (CTE) and join to it like a normal table (hopefully the TO_CHAR() is not necessary and tb1.cutoff_date is a date datatype):

```
WITH date_tbl(dates) AS (
  SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019')+LEVEL-1, 'yyyy-mm-dd')  
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= SYSDATE - (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019') + 1 )
)
SELECT netcash 
FROM tb1 
  JOIN date_tbl
    ON tb1.cutoff_date = date_tbl.dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're looking for here, but in your example it could be like this:

```
SELECT NETCASH FROM TB1 WHERE to_char(tb1.CUTOFFDATE,'yyyy-mm-dd') IN (
SELECT to_char(dates,'yyyy-mm-dd') dates
FROM (
    SELECT TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019') + ROWNUM - 1 dates
        FROM (
          SELECT ROWNUM FROM (
            SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= sysdate - (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019') + 1 )
          )
    )
);
```

Though personally, unless CUTOFFDATE is a string in that format, I would just remove both of the TO_CHAR, if you need midnight you can use TRUNC(date).

You could also do this:

```
SELECT NETCASH 
FROM TB1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT to_char(dates,'yyyy-mm-dd') dates
    FROM (
        SELECT TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019') + ROWNUM - 1 dates
            FROM (
              SELECT ROWNUM FROM (
                SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= sysdate - (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019') + 1 )
              )
        )
    )) as DATES
    ON dates.dates = to_char(tb1.CUTOFFDATE,'yyyy-mm-dd')
;
```

But these two queries will yield very different results, use the one that matches your intent.

Comment: I tried to write my query as simple as possible but let me explain it better

Comment: I understood the query, just not your intent. Cheers!